# How do I make the scrub (Z) gesture close javascript dropdown menus / tooltip dialogs etc?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

iOS VoiceOver has support to close native popups (alerts, select dropdown, etc.) with the scrub gesture (i.e. two fingers dragged in a Z shape).  However, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do it on dropdowns displayed through javascript, like dropdown menus.

I know that the scrub gesture (while VoiceOver is enabled) essentially clicks the "Back" button, so therefore I can intercept that by calling `history.pushState()` when the popup opens, and then listening for the "popstate" event.  However, that seems like it opens a big can of worms.  For example, since opening a popup adjusts the history stack, closing the popup causes the forward button to become enabled.  Plus, it sends focus to the back button even if I call `preventDefault()` in the "popstate" listener.

Another approach would be to programmatically detect the scrub gesture and then (try to) cancel the default action of essentially clicking the back button.  But that seems like a lot of work too.

So, is there a good way to detect and intercept the scrub gesture in javascript?

Comment: At one point (several years ago), my app was listening for the ESC key (27) in the key handler and the Z scrub would generate the same escape.  Not sure if that's still true.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work anymore.  Too bad!   Thanks for the response anyway.